# Merge imagefiles and convert to PDF in Powerapps

Tags: powerapps

Is it possible to merge multiple images * (jpeg) in one image and convert it to PDF in PowerApps?

Edit: * uploaded via mobile browser.

Comment: If you want to view the PDF in PowerApps, you can convert the images to one PDF using Word or PowerPoint and then import that file in your app as a "Controls" -> "PDF Viewer". If that wasn't what you were looking for, could you provide more detail as to what you are trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: See edited question.